# When updating a <div> with jQuery, CSS rules are not applied to new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When the page first loads everything works perfectly. I then give the user several buttons to select alternate photo galleries. Once they click, some jQuery grabs another neigh-identical code block as what was originally in the `<div>` (with new IDs & banners). However, none of the CSS (located in an external file) is applied to the new segment of code inside the `<div>`.

The contents of "galBox" are completely replaced.

Here is the page I'm working on: http://www.cwholemaniii.com/pages/photography/index.shtml

And the (relevant) code I'm working with:

```js
function loadGallery(pickedGallery) {
  $("#galBox").html("<object data='" + pickedGallery.toLowerCase() + ".html'>");
}
```

```css
.slideShowBox {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 76%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slideShowIFrame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.galleryBox {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>4
  <input type="button" onClick="loadGallery(this.value);" value="Top_Ten" />
  <input type="button" onClick="loadGallery(this.value);" value="Weddings" />
  <input type="button" onClick="loadGallery(this.value);" value="Animals" />
  <input type="button" onClick="loadGallery(this.value);" value="Portraits" />
  <input type="button" onClick="loadGallery(this.value);" value="Sky" />

</p>


<div class="galleryBox" id="galBox">
  <p>
    <img class="galleryHeader" src="/images/banners/top_ten_banner.jpg" id="animals" />
  </p>
  <h3>Top Ten</h3>
  <div class="slideShowBox">
    <iframe class="slideShowIFrame" src='https://flickrit.com/slideshowholder.php?height=75&size=big&speed=4.5&count=100&setId=72157650225649348&trans=1&thumbnails=1&transition=4&layoutType=responsive&sort=0' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not the same HTML

Answer (score 3):

You are loading `#galBox` with totally different content.
in the first example (initial state) you have:

```
<div class="galleryBox" id="galBox">
  <p>
    <img class="galleryHeader" src="/images/banners/top_ten_banner.jpg" id="animals" />
  </p>
  <h3>Top Ten</h3>
  <div class="slideShowBox">
    <iframe class="slideShowIFrame" src='[url]' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

but you replace it with

```
<div class="galleryBox" id="galBox">
    <object date='[etc]'></object>
</div>
```

None of the css you have included applies to your newly created object.

Comment: Ah, Thanks! I misunderstood how 
   ("#galBox").html("<object data='" + pickedGallery.toLowerCase() + ".html'>"); 
was working.

What I needed was 
  $('#galBox').load(pickedGallery.toLowerCase() + ".html");

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I misunderstood how 
   `("#galBox").html("<object data='" + pickedGallery.toLowerCase() + ".html'>");` was working.

What I needed was 
   `$('#galBox').load(pickedGallery.toLowerCase() + ".html")`

This was due to the  adding in all sorts of additional code in a way I was not expecting.